# Nested Fragments with MapView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a MapView and it works by itself. When I launch that same fragment inside another fragment the app crashes.

My app crashes after `mapView.onCreate(null)` with the following stack. However it only crashes when it is nested in another fragment.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1282)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3051)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2998)
        at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2537)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1318)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:738)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

This is my fragment which works by itself

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
    setup();
    return view;
}

private void setup() {
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapViewFragment);
    mapView.onCreate(null);
    mapView.onResume();

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}
```

and this is how I am nesting the fragments

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutBuffer, new MapViewFragment()).commit();
```

The id is from a framelayout.
If I change to another Fragment, the other fragment displays just fine, so it something to do with the MapView.

Both fragments also do not contain any ImageView, any help about this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by calling the setup method inside the `onResume()` and changing `view.findViewById()` to `getView().findViewbyId()`

Edit: Actually that did not fix the problem. I added a delay before creating the map in another thread, and that seemed to fix.